# Выборка с указанием нескольких параметров

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с непонятной ошибкой при написании хранимки для выборки всех клиентов, которые закреплены за указанными адресами.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`grasa_db`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetClients`(
likeParam NVARCHAR(50),
pageSizeParam INT,
pageIndexParam INT,
idPersonnelParam CHAR(36))
BEGIN
DECLARE startIndex INT;
SET startIndex = pageSizeParam * pageIndexParam;

SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
FROM client 
    WHERE 
    (client.IdAddress IN (SELECT personneladdress.IdAddress FROM personneladdress WHERE personneladdress.IdPersonnel = idPersonnelParam) AND
    FirstName Like(CASE WHEN likeParam IS NULL THEN client.FirstName ELSE concat('%', likeParam, '%') END) OR
    LastName Like(CASE WHEN likeParam IS NULL THEN client.LastName ELSE   concat('%', likeParam, '%')   END) OR
    MiddleName Like(CASE WHEN likeParam IS NULL THEN client.MiddleName ELSE   concat('%', likeParam, '%')   END))
    LIMIT startIndex, pageSizeParam;
END
```

Так вот в чем суть: передавая ID персонала, я получаю перечень адресов, за которыми он закреплен. Далее выбираются клиенты, которые закреплены за каким-то из выбранных адресом. Все вроде бы работает, но когда добавляется проверка на поиск по ФИО, то выводятся все клиенты по всем адресам, даже по тем, за которыми не закреплен указанный персонал.

Answer (score 1):

Я извиняюсь, нужно было освежить голову) Вся проблема в скобке, которую я не там поставил

```
client.IdAddress IN (SELECT personneladdress.IdAddress FROM personneladdress WHERE personneladdress.IdPersonnel = idPersonnelParam) AND
    (FirstName Like(CASE WHEN likeParam IS NULL THEN client.FirstName ELSE concat('%', likeParam, '%') END) OR
    LastName Like(CASE WHEN likeParam IS NULL THEN client.LastName ELSE   concat('%', likeParam, '%')   END) OR
    MiddleName Like(CASE WHEN likeParam IS NULL THEN client.MiddleName ELSE   concat('%', likeParam, '%')   END))
```